# Adding new JTable to JPanel on ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

While I am using

```
pnlmain.add(table);
```

It's showing table without `ColumnNames`, instead when I used

```
pnlmain.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

it's showing nothing in the panel. So, what to do for showing `ColumnNames` to the `JTable` while the table is displaying in `JPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

A component can only have a single parent. Make sure your code only adds the table to the scroll pane and no other panel.

Also, if you add a component to a visible GUI you need to revalidate() and repaint() the panel.

If you need more help, then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use scroll bar, use below code to show column names:

```
pnlmain.add(table.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
pnlmain.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```